# Java, macro code, function address

Tags: java, function, macros

I am beginner with Java, and I would like to write some code like this :

```
TEST(myfunction(1, 2, 3));
```

Where **TEST** is :

- Either a macro as used in C
- Either a function which need the address of the function *myfunction*

In my code, I would like **TEST** to do some code :

```
TEST(function) {
    if (function()) 
        // code
    else
        //code
}
```

I know pointers are not usable in Java.
An idea to help me ?

[EDIT]
Here is another example :

```
TEST(myfunction(1, 2, 3));
```

Where TEST is implemented :

```
void TEST (function(args[])) {
try {
    function();
}
catch (Exception e) {
    // Exception happened !
}
```

}

Thanks to that, with only one code line, I will be able to use *try catch* !

Comment: That looks like it could simply be replaced with a function definition with a single boolean parameter... as in: public boolean test(boolean b) { ... }...

Comment: @perp No, I can't pass boolean as parameter. I need to call function in **TEST** to execute it and do some treatment using return value

Comment: `with only one code line, I will be able to use try catch !`. Please don't do this. In Java you use exceptions, if you don't want them, then don't use Java.

Comment: @Ishtar I never said I don't want use exceptions ! I only want to write several lines in one line. I do this easily in C with macro, and I try to do the same in Java

Comment: In reality when you get an exception, it is exceptional and you don't want to continue as if nothing happened, (which this appears to assume)

Comment: If you want several lines in one, just place a catch block around the whole section of code, or perhaps just `throws` the exception from the method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java doesn't have pointers to functions. The typical way functions are passed around in Java is to pass an object that implements `Runnable`.

**EDIT:** I've revised my example to be closer to your second case.

In your case, where you want a boolean return value, you can define your own interface:

```
public interface BooleanTest {
    boolean test(Object... args) throws Exception;
}
```

and then later:

```
class MyTest implements BooleanTest {
    private boolean result;
    public MyTest(int a, int b, int c) {
        result = a + b == c;
    }
    // stupid test -- don't _have_ to declare "throws Exception"
    public boolean test(Object... args) {
        return result && args.length == 3;
    }
}

TEST(new MyTest(1, 2, 3));
```

and inside TEST:

```
TEST(BooleanTest test) {
    try {
        if (test.test("Jack", "and", "Jill")) {
            // ...
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to make your answer more clear you should at least explain why OP's solutions don't work in Java.

Comment: @Ted Hopp Sorry, but Runnable call function in new thread, here I want execution done in current thread

Comment: @TheFrancisOne A Runnable can be used to create a new Thread object, but that's not its only use. A Runnable in itself does not create a new thread; it's merely an object with a run() method that declares itself to be a Runnable.

Comment: In this case, where you want to return something, a `Callable<Boolean>` seems to be the better choice than `Runnable`.

Comment: @Ted Hopp Thanks but it's not enough in my case. Here your TEST function take an object as parameter `TEST(BooleanTest test)` and after call the correct method. But in my case, I don't know what method excute, and my `TEST` function must use this method as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get an interface implementation as a parameter. Like this:

```
public static void testFunction(new FunctionContainer() {

  @Override
  public int function() {
    ...
  }

};);
```

Comment: Interface is not that I want. Because here I want to execute method (or function) and do some treatment

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do this in java as methods are not Objects.  To achieve your desired functionality you would need to wrap your function/method inside another object.

```
 // Define a function interface that your test method takes as an argument.
 public interface Function {
     public abstract void doFunction();
 }

 // Test code
 public void test(Function function) {
     function.doFunction();
 }

 // You can then pass an implementation of Function to your test method
 test(new Function() {
     public void doFunction() {
         // Function implementation
     }
  });
```